# Is it possible to package and distribute Laravel based project with all of its dependencies included?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, dependency-management

My client cannot install anything besides what is available via Debian packages, and so installing Composer is not an option (unless a Laravel / Composer package exists).

The best solution would be if the client could just unzip the project along with all of its (Laravel, Composer) dependencies and it would just work.

Is something like this possible to achieve? How?

Comment: Just zip everything up, including the Composer vendor directory...!?

Answer (score 2):

> The best solution would be if the client could just unzip the project
>   along with all of its (Laravel, Composer) dependencies and it would
>   just work.

Yes - this will work

> Is something like this possible to achieve? How?

Like you said - if you have the project running on your directory - just zip it up (including the `/vendors` folder) - and they can unzip it. There is no need to "install" Laravel.

Once unzipped - the client should still be able to run `php artisan migrate` to do the database table migrations

Edit: actually - why cant they just run

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

or

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Its not a package - but its installed via PHP? [See composer install docs for more info](https://getcomposer.org/download/).